# PHP/MYSQL: How can I calculate value of field + other field + other field

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a mysql table, which contains a field called 'id', 'name' and 'number'.

Every row's field 'number', has got a number.

```
id   name   number

1    test 30

2    test2  40

3    lala   23


total = 93
```

How can I calculate (plus) all the rows' number?

```
$row['number']+$row['number']+$row['number'] = .. an other number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(number) AS total FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT name, SUM(number) FROM table GROUP BY name`

I assume you want to have a sum by name.

`SELECT SUM(number) FROM table`

Without grouping.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum for more info

Answer (score 1):

try to do thuis

```
 select number ,sum(number) as total from table;
```

then do

```
$row['total']  // and it gives u the total sum
```

Answer (score 1):

At the PHP level:

```
$cnt = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $cnt += $row['yourfield'];
}
```

At the MySQL leve:

```
SELECT SUM(yourfield)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY yourfield
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query the table like this:

```
select sum(number) from table;
```

and have mysql calculate it for you.